# a:hover blur effect (using text shadow) on everything but the hovered a link?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have seen a few responses for this, but struggling to incorporate it into my code.

So at the moment, the letter on hover will blur, but how can i make it so on hover the other letters blur, and the one on hover remains in focus ?

Along these lines..

https://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/

Here is my code..

```js
    // append textshadow class to HTML node if supported (Modernizr will do the same)
    if (document.createElement("detect").style.textShadow === "") {
     document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className += " textshadow";
    }
```

```css
 body
    { 
     background-color: #eee;
        text-shadow: 12px 12px 8px #000000;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white; 
    }
    
    
    .textshadow a.blur,
    
    .textshadow a.blur.out:hover, 
    .textshadow a.blur.out:focus 
    {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     outline: 0 none;
    
     -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
     -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
     transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    
     text-shadow: 0 0 5px white, 12px 12px 8px #000000;
    }
    
    .textshadow a.blur.out,
    
    .textshadow a.blur:hover, 
    .textshadow a.blur:focus
    {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     outline: 0 none;
    
     -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
     -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
     transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    
     text-shadow: 0 0 0 white, 12px 12px 8px #000000;
    }
    
    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="basilswan">
    <div class="basilswan-b"><a href="http://sarahboulton.co.uk" class="blur out">B</a></div>
    <div class="basilswan-a"><a href="http://sarahboulton.co.uk" class="blur out">a</a></div>
    <div class="basilswan-s"><a href="http://sarahboulton.co.uk" class="blur out">s</a></div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to catch the hover event on the parent event and then select all children which you are not hovering on. You can achieve that by doing:  `.parent:hover child:not(:hover)`.

That's the only thing I changed in the snippet below. You should note however, that the parent section in your code uses the whole width, so that everything gets blurred when the mouse is hovering on the right side of the text. But I guess your layout is not final and will be horizontal anyways (like a menu), where this is not a problem.

```js
// append textshadow class to HTML node if supported (Modernizr will do the same)
    if (document.createElement("detect").style.textShadow === "") {
     document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className += " textshadow";
    }
```

```css
body
    { 
     background-color: #eee;
        text-shadow: 12px 12px 8px #000000;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white; 
    }
    
    
    .textshadow a.blur,
    
    .basilswan:hover a.blur.out:not(:hover)
    {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     outline: 0 none;
    
     -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
     -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
     transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    
     text-shadow: 0 0 5px white, 12px 12px 8px #000000;
    }
    
    .textshadow a.blur.out,
    
    .textshadow a.blur:hover, 
    .textshadow a.blur:focus
    {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
     outline: 0 none;
    
     -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
     -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
     transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    
     text-shadow: 0 0 0 white, 12px 12px 8px #000000;
    }
    
    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<section class="basilswan">
    <div class="basilswan-b"><a href="http://sarahboulton.co.uk" class="blur out">B</a></div>
    <div class="basilswan-a"><a href="http://sarahboulton.co.uk" class="blur out">a</a></div>
    <div class="basilswan-s"><a href="http://sarahboulton.co.uk" class="blur out">s</a></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias !

Okay so I have applied it to the page we are working on..

http://sarahboulton.co.uk/chapelbedroom.html (has been applied to the 'basil swan' letters, might have to refresh a few times to get around to it)..

 and the mouse being to the right hand side is solved, but then animation now seems to only be working in on direction (mouse on, and not for mouse off) .. the blur is working.. but the 2nd static shadows are sort of glitching on hover, disappearing for the 400ms that the animation is scheduled for .. which wasn't happening on the test page.. ?

Comment: You can add the `transition: 400ms ease 100ms;` to the `a` tags, which makes the transition work for the "hover off" event.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're achieving your blur with the `text-shadow` property... in my opinion it would be better to set `filter: blur(5px)` on all links that the user is not hovering on and get completely rid of that `text-shadow`. That would solve the problem with the glitching that you described...